# Integrate jQAssistant in Maven build using profile and running server

Tags: maven, jqassistant

I'm trying to integrate jQAssistant into my existing Maven build. I have a hierarchy of POMs, but basically the top POM defines what the build does. That's where I have my `<pluginManagement>` and my build plugins that are always used. I also have a couple of Maven profiles for special builds.

So, I want to scan all classes during build time and aggregate the results into a running server to have a fully populated Neo4J database after the build of all my Maven modules. The database should contain my whole code base.

Analysing and checking would be a different step, I don't want to do that directly when building a Maven module.

The examples I see all build a local database and then check the classes against it. As far as I understand it, I would have to run the server as a daemon and then configure the Maven plugin to use the 'bolt' URI to populate it - is this right?

Also, since I don't want to slow down the 'normal' build, I added a Maven profile to active the jQAssistant scan. However, this only works on my top POM, but doesn't work in any other Maven project/module. The inheritance of profiles is a normal and expected Maven feature - so what am I doing wrong?

Here's my parent POM. Just to see whether the profile is active, I added PMD as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <groupId>foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.50.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.buschmais.jqassistant</groupId>
          <artifactId>jqassistant-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <useExecutionRootAsProjectRoot>true</useExecutionRootAsProjectRoot>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

    <profile>
      <id>architecture</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>pmd</goal>
                  <goal>cpd</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>com.buschmais.jqassistant</groupId>
            <artifactId>jqassistant-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>scan</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>scan</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>

</project>
```

When I run `mvn clean package -P architecture` on a Maven project with that parent POM, I see the following output, which shows that the profile is active:

```
09:30:12.316 [INFO] 
09:30:12.316 [INFO] --- maven-pmd-plugin:3.5:pmd (default) @ util-type ---
09:30:15.073 [INFO] 
09:30:15.073 [INFO] --- maven-pmd-plugin:3.5:cpd (default) @ util-type ---
09:30:15.976 [INFO]
```

However, `jqassistant-maven-plugin` is nowhere.

Now, if I add it to my normal `<build>` plugins:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.buschmais.jqassistant</groupId>
      <artifactId>jqassistant-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>scan</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>scan</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

then I see the following output for `mvn clean package` for my **parent POM**:

```
10:38:14.252 [INFO] --- jqassistant-maven-plugin:1.5.0:scan (scan) @ parent ---
10:38:15.684 [INFO] Loaded jQAssistant plugins [CDI, Common, Core Analysis, Core Report, EJB3, GraphML, JAX-RS, JPA 2, JSON, JUnit, Java, Java 8, Java EE 6, Maven 3, OSGi, RDBMS, Spring, TestNG, Tycho, XML, YAML].
10:38:15.952 [INFO] Connecting to store at 'file:/C:/jp/maven-parents/parent/target/jqassistant/store/'
10:38:20.058 [INFO] Initializing embedded Neo4j server 3.x
10:38:20.078 [INFO] Resetting store.
10:38:21.515 [INFO] Reset finished (removed 8453 nodes, 29427 relations).
10:38:22.372 [INFO] Entering C:/jp/maven-parents/parent/target/failsafe-reports
10:38:22.378 [INFO] Leaving C:/jp/maven-parents/parent/target/failsafe-reports (1 entries, 4 ms)
```

However, in my Maven project, I don't see any jQAssistant output.

Starting `mvn help:effective-pom -Parchitecture` gives me the same output for the parent project and the Maven module:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>pmd</goal>
          <goal>cpd</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          ...
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      ...
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.buschmais.jqassistant</groupId>
    <artifactId>jqassistant-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>scan</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>scan</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <useExecutionRootAsProjectRoot>true</useExecutionRootAsProjectRoot>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <useExecutionRootAsProjectRoot>true</useExecutionRootAsProjectRoot>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we are, some years later  :-)

And coming back to my mistake!

The problem here was the Maven phase. The jQAssistant plugin Mojo `scan` has the Maven phase `post-integration-test` by default.

However, we never do `mvn clean install` in my company, we only do `mvn clean package` and install using Jenkins, Nexus etc. etc.

So, it was my fault to not force the plugin to the `package` phase.

That's how it works:

```
<profile>
  <id>jqassistant</id>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.buschmais.jqassistant</groupId>
        <artifactId>jqassistant-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>scan-software</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>scan</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my projects I have a parent POM with the following plugin management section:

```xml
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.buschmais.jqassistant</groupId>
                <artifactId>jqassistant-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jqassistant.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useExecutionRootAsProjectRoot>true</useExecutionRootAsProjectRoot>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scan</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>scan</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>analyze</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>analyze</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnSeverity>MAJOR</failOnSeverity>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

I also defined the following profile, which I use to run jQAsssistant:

```xml
<profile>
    <id>verify-architecture</id>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.buschmais.jqassistant</groupId>
                <artifactId>jqassistant-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Using `mvn -P verify-archicture clean install` I can scan and analyze my projects.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, but for some reason, it doesn't work in my build. When the plugin is called within the normal build, it works, but not within a profile.

Comment: It is difficult to finde the problem without your project setup. Is it a public project?

Comment: This looks like a problem in the setup of the Maven project. Just to avoid misunderstandings: beside the pluginManagement in your parent pom there's also a declaration of the plugin itself? What are you executing on the command line? Can you drop some snippets of your setup here?

Comment: The project is not public, sorry! I tried to document what's happening (see above). Somehow the execution of the plugin is not inherited from the parent POM to the Maven projects.

Comment: Can you execute ```mvn help:effective-pom -Pyour-profile``` in your child project and verify if the jQA Maven plugin is active there? Otherwise: Can you strip down your setup to a (anonymized) demonstrator example that shows the problem?

Comment: Sorry for the delay! I executed it and got the result as decribed in my updated original question above. By the way: I'll be away till November 9th.